# Volume integral for conserved current

Tags: integration

Show that for a current $\vec{J}(\vec{r})$ such that $\vec{\nabla}\cdot J=0$ and $\vec{J}$ is zero outside the volume then
$$\int_V dV'J_i(\vec{r'})=0$$
and
$$\int_V dV'J_i(\vec{r'})r'_j=-\int_V dV' J_j(\vec{r})\vec{r_i}'$$

by considering $\partial_i(J_ir_j)$ and $\partial_i(J_ir_jr_k)$ over a large volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as $\nabla \cdot \vec J=0$, we can write

$$\vec J=\vec J+\vec r\left(\nabla \cdot \vec J\right)$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \vec J\,dV &=\int_V \vec J\,dV +\int_V\vec r \left(\nabla \cdot \vec J\right)\,dV\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\vec J=0$ outside $V$, we have for any $V'$ that contains $V$

$$\int_{V'} \vec J\,dV=\int_V \vec J\,dV\tag 2$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \vec J\,dV &=\int_{V'} \vec J\,dV +\int_{V'}\vec r \left(\nabla \cdot \vec J\right)\,dV\\\\
&=\int_{V'} \vec J\,dV +\sum_i \hat x_i\int_{V'}x_i \left(\nabla \cdot \vec J\right)\,dV\\\\
&=\int_{V'} \vec J\,dV +\sum_i \hat x_i\int_{V'} \left(\nabla \cdot x_i\vec J\right)\,dV-\int_{V'}\vec J\,dV\\\\
&=\oint_{\partial V'}\vec r \left(\hat n\cdot \vec J\right)\,dS\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

since $\vec J=0$ outside $V$.  And we are done!

Comment: beautiful proof, I will try to prove the second statement, any hint about how to go with it

Comment: Sure.  Just follow an analogous procedure.

Comment: sorry how did you go to the last line

Comment: Do you mean "$=0$?"

Comment: nope to get the integral in term of surface integral

Comment: @Thegame That relies on direct application of the divergence theorem. :-)